# Find polynomial equation for a cardioid in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

We have the cardioid with equations:
$$x(\theta)=\cos\theta+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\theta)$$
$$y(\theta)=\sin\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)$$

I have to show that you can define this cardioid with a polynomial in two variables.

My approach, I defined the auxiliary variables $u,v$ such that,
$$\begin{matrix}
u=\cos(2\theta)&\Rightarrow&\cos\theta =\frac{\sqrt{1+u}}{2}\\
v=\sin(2\theta)&\Rightarrow&\sin\theta =\frac{\sqrt{1+-u}}{2}
\end{matrix}$$
and since $u^2+v^2=1$, it is,
$$x^2+y^2-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}+u\frac{\sqrt{1+u}}{2}+v\frac{\sqrt{1-u}}{2}=ux+vy$$
but I got stuck here, any tips on how can I continue?

Comment: I guess you used the identity $$\cos^2\theta = \dfrac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2},$$ thus if you set $u = \cos(2\theta)$, it should be $\cos(\theta) = \pm\sqrt{\dfrac{1+u}{2}}$.

Comment: well that's true, but one step at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the two equations

$$x(\theta)=\cos\theta+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\theta) \tag{1}$$
$$y(\theta)=\sin\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta) \tag{2}$$

By squaring both equations and adding (this gives the useful "expression" $\cos^2+\sin^2$ for both $\theta$ and $2\theta$):

$$\begin{align}
x^2+y^2&=1+\frac{1}{4}+\cos\theta \cos2\theta+\sin\theta\sin2\theta \\[1em]
&=\frac{5}{4}+\cos\theta \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

While from (1) and the identity $\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$:

$$\begin{align}
\cos^2\theta+\cos\theta&=x+\frac{1}{2} \\[1em]
\cos^2\theta+\cos\theta+\frac{1}{4}&=x+\frac{3}{4} &(\text{completing the square})\\[1em]
\left(\cos\theta+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2&=x+\frac{3}{4} \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

From (3):

$$\begin{align}
x^2+y^2-\frac{3}{4}&=\cos\theta+\frac{1}{2} &\implies \\[1em]
\left(x^2+y^2-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2&=\left(\cos\theta+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 &\stackrel{(4)}{\implies} \\[1em]
\left(x^2+y^2-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2&=x+\frac{3}{4}
\end{align}$$

which can be simplified further if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Outline: The first equation can be rewritten as 
$$x+\frac{1}{2}=\cos \theta+ cos^2\theta,\tag{1}$$ and the second as 
$$y=\sin\theta(1+\cos\theta).\tag{2}$$ Thus, dividing we find that
$$\tan\theta=\frac{y}{x+\frac{1}{2}}.$$
Square and add $1$. We get $\sec^2\theta$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. So now we have $\cos^2\theta$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.  Rewrite (1) as 
$$cos\theta=\cos^2\theta-x-\frac{1}{2}.$$
Square both sides and substitute for $\cos^2\theta$. Simplify to taste.